# Correlation Heatmap - Seaborn -> Mask and style wont produce triangle correlation Matrix

Tags: python, matrix, seaborn, correlation

I try to produce a correlation matrix similar to this:
[target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtCe9.jpg)

But my results look like this:
[current results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRr5t.jpg)

I use the same styling and mask, but I don't get why I get all these grey squares. Tried different styling, which doesn't change my plots. My code is below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=routing_names)

sns.set_theme(style="white")
sns.set_style("white")

corrMatrix = df.corr()

mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corrMatrix, dtype=bool))
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 20, as_cmap=True)

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(39,39)})

sns.heatmap(corrMatrix,mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center=0, square=False, linewidths=.5, annot=True, fmt='.1g', annot_kws={"fontsize": 6})
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.3)

plt.savefig("output.svg")
plt.show()
```

Comment: `sns.set()` also resets the background color to seaborn's default grey.  So, you need `sns.set_theme(style="white")`and `sns.set_style("white")` after calling `sns.set()`.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code with my own data and for me it looks like as the the line of code makes it not possible for you:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.3)
```

It overwrites default properties, which will be in your code as long as you reimport matplotlib.pyplot, so reimport matplotlib.pyplot and remove the line of code above, then it should work.

Hint:

For the masking you can actually just do:

```
mask = np.triu(corrMatrix)
```

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust()` will just add extra padding at the left and bottom of the current figure.  This will be reset when a new figure is created.  In general, `mask = np.triu(corrMatrix)` is not a good idea, as it would lead to all the zero values in the matrix being unmasked.